# Parameter 0 of method listenerAdapter in "package/class" required a bean of type 'com.example.messagingrabbitmq.Receiver' that could not be found

Tags: spring, docker, rabbitmq, javabeans, amqp

Hеllo, all,

I am building a simple RabbitMQ AMQP server with Spring/Docker to run the server itself and I am following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/#scratch

The classes are literally copied from there.

I have 3 classes in src/main/java/com.example.messagingrabbitmq and they are the following:

MessagingRabbitmqApplication:

```
package com.example.messagingrabbitmq;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MessagingRabbitmqApplication {

    static final String topicExchangeName = "spring-boot-exchange";

    static final String queueName = "spring-boot";

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo.bar.#");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(MessagingRabbitmqApplication.class, args).close();
    }

}
```

Receiver:

```
package com.example.messagingrabbitmq;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

}
```

Runner:

```
package com.example.messagingrabbitmq;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private final Receiver receiver;

    public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(MessagingRabbitmqApplication.topicExchangeName, "foo.bar.baz", "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
        receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

}
```

I tried to run the program from the MessagingRabbitmqApplication java class, but resulted in the following error:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method listenerAdapter in com.example.messagingrabbitmq.MessagingRabbitmqApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.messagingrabbitmq.Receiver' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.messagingrabbitmq.Receiver' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to create a Receiver Bean in Receiver.java class with the following, but it resulted in the same error:

```
   @Bean
    Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }
```

I also have a question on how to set up my application.properties file so the Queues/Exchanges can be set up in my running Docker container? It is currently running on 'localhost:15672'.

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I checked your existing code, it's working fine.

TestAmqpApplication :

```
package com.example.testamqp;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestAmqpApplication {

    static final String topicExchangeName = "spring-boot-exchange";

    static final String queueName = "spring-boot";

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo.bar.#");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestAmqpApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Receiver:

```
package com.example.testamqp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

}
```

Runner:

```
package com.example.testamqp;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private final Receiver receiver;

    public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(TestAmqpApplication.topicExchangeName, "foo.bar.baz", "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
        receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

}
```

Screenshot of the console output:

[image]

Compile your project with maven properly. Do Maven `clean` and `install` phases again.

If you are still facing issue, then do this steps:

- Also, invalidate cache for the project in Intellij.
  [image]
- Last but not the least, create a fresh project and try again.

Comment: Updated all as you suggested and the error is still the same.

Comment: @Jmork It should work. Please provide the codebase on the github. I will check.

Comment: @Jmork Compile the project with maven and try again. See if all the class in the same package.

Comment: https://github.com/Jmorkcho/rabbitMQ Here is the repository - I did all the maven lifecycle operations, but still receiving the same error.

Comment: @Jmork Checking now..

Comment: UPDATE: I can manage to run the application when I package it and run it with "java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" command in the Terminal, but cannot run it with "Run" from Intellij.

The question remains - how does the application know which server to use(in this case my locally running Docker container)? How can I configure it manually, because if I try to add these [application properties](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-03/messaging-using-rabbitmq-in-spring-boot-application/#applicationproperties) they all are grey and marked as "Unused property".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252292/discussion-between-anish-b-and-jmork).